# Why is my if statement skipping the else?

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, counting

I'm writing a small program that count the lines of code. Here is the definition of a line of code:
- any line that contains code necessary for the program to function.
- blank line is not a line of code.
- comment is not a line of code.
- if there's code and a comment right after on the same line, it counts as well.

So I have this piece of code (simple if statement):

```
found = lineRead.find("/*");
if(found != string::npos)
{
    found = lineRead.find("*/");
    if(found != string::npos)
        inComment = false;
    else
        inComment == true;
}
return inComment;
```

---

Assume that

```
String lineRead = "cout<<\"helloworld!\";/*blockcomment"
Bool inComment (is true if the previous line didn't have end block comment token)
```

So my program reaches the first if statement because it found `/*` in that line, looks for `*/`, goes to the second if statement then jumps straight to the return statement without changing `inComment` (which is supposed to be set to `true` because the text on the next line is still inside the block comment).

Anyone know why that is?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? The problem is staring you in the face. Really?

Comment: The `if/else` could be replaced by `inComment = (found == string::npos);`

Comment: @KeithThompson: Or `return (found == string::npos);`.

Comment: @staticx: Which raises another point: What's the value of `inComment` if the outer `if` condition is false?

Comment: the problem was fixed. Thank you! I'm exhausted and tired. I just missed this very silly mistake.

Comment: Can your parser handle this statement, `std::string begin_comment = "/*";`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is the infamous "double equal sign."
`inComment == true;`

In C++, `==` is used for compare, NOT for assignment.  I think what you want is:
  `inComment = true;`

Comment: boy do I feel stupid...I pulled an all-nighter. Really can't think straight apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Double equal sign is for comparison not assignment. Probably just a typo as I assume you know that. But yea, change `==` to just `=` :-)